# View already being created in Database now recompiling gives error ORA-00998: must name this expression with a column alias

Tags: sql, oracle, view, compilation

My View is already in database with column alias not mentioned after my expression in select query:

```
select
a.column1,
a.column2,
decode (a.column3,'HAHAHA', b.column21 || ' : ' || a.column4 || ' BYE : ' || d.column31,   b.column22) , 
a.column5
from 
a , b ,d
WHERE a.column1 = b.column21 
AND a.column2= d.column31 (+);
```

What I am unable to understand that if I need to recompile same view it gives error  ORA-00998: must name this expression with a column alias.
which i understand is for my decode expression missing the alias name .

But what surprises me is how it got into database.

am unable to understand this .
Plz let me know how it might have got into db.

Comment: so the view exists in your database but has no column alias? what is shown as column header text if you select from this view? oracle always force to create a column alias, i guess the generated code for your view does not match with the real view. how do you generated this code? another option is that the db is from an older version where it was allowed to not use an alias.

Comment: Can you show us the results of the query `select column_name from user_tab_cols where table_name='<your view name>'` ?